# I am trying to input text into a <textarea> but once I click the add button, the text area within the page goes blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am trying to create a webpage form and i am stuck on trying to get the fields to go into the text area i have on the webpage. I am new to programming so please bear with me. Here is my html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lab8.js"></script>
 <title>Input Form Web Page</title>

</head>
<body>
 <h1>Input Form Webpage</h1>
     <p>Enter two or more names in the field below,
     and the sorted list of names will appear in the
     textarea.</p>
 <form name="theform" >
  First Name: <br/>
     <input type="text" name="newname" size="20" /><br/>
     <input type="button" name="addname" value="Add"
     onclick="SortNames();">
     <br/>
  Last Name: <br/>
  <input type="text" name="newname" size="20" /><br/>
     <input type="button" name="addname" value="Add"
     onclick="SortNames();">
     <br/>
  <h2>Sorted Names</h2>
     <textarea cols="60" rows="10" name="sorted">
     The sorted names will appear here.
     </textarea>
     </form>


</body><br/>
<footer>
Marco Deleon,
Course CRN - 21819,
Date Completed: 11/6/2016,
Assignment # Lab9
</footer>
</html>
```

This is a default javascript file that i was given by my professor to use as an example but i just cant get it to work.

```html
// initialize the counter and the array
var numbernames=0;
var names = new Array();
function SortNames() {
   // Get the name from the text field
   thename=document.theform.newname.value;
   // Add the name to the array
   names[numbernames]=thename;
   // Increment the counter
   numbernames++;
   // Sort the array
   names.sort();
   document.theform.sorted.value=names.join("\n");
}
```

Comment: so basically you want to inject those text boxes value inside textarea by angular js tight?

Comment: I have been able to inject them but i am wondering if its possible to remove the sort function and just have it list the text in the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all get all elements with the specified name by using `getElementsByName()`. The `getElementsByName()` method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified name (the value of the name attribute), as a `NodeList object`.

The `NodeList object` represents a collection of nodes. The nodes can be accessed by index numbers. The index starts at 0

Try this:

```js
var numbernames=0;
var names = new Array();
function SortNames() {
   // Get the name from the text field
   for(var i = 0; i< 2; i++){
   var thename=document.getElementsByName('newname')[i].value;
   // Add the name to the array
   names[i]=thename;
   // Increment the counter
   //numbernames++;
   // Sort the array
   //names.sort();
   
  }
  
  document.getElementsByName('sorted')[0].value=names.join("\n");
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lab8.js"></script>
 <title>Input Form Web Page</title>

</head>
<body>
 <h1>Input Form Webpage</h1>
     <p>Enter two or more names in the field below,
     and the sorted list of names will appear in the
     textarea.</p>
 <form name="theform" >
  First Name: <br/>
     <input type="text" name="newname" size="20" /><br/>
     
     <br/>
  Last Name: <br/>
  <input type="text" name="newname" size="20" /><br/>
     <input type="button" name="addname" value="Add"
     onclick="SortNames();">
     <br/>
  <h2>Sorted Names</h2>
     <textarea cols="60" rows="10" name="sorted" id ="name">
     The sorted names will appear here.
     </textarea>
     </form>


</body><br/>
<footer>
Marco Deleon,
Course CRN - 21819,
Date Completed: 11/6/2016,
Assignment # Lab9
</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tested thoroughly this snippet?

Comment: @Jigar7521 Yes. I have provided a snippet too

Comment: yes @senjuti, of course i am talking about your's code snippt

Comment: I have tested it with the above solution and it works now, but I am wondering if i could change it from sorting alphabetically to just sorting it as a list.

Comment: Would it also be possible of having the fields for input there with the name and, last name, professor name, and course number. Once those have been filled out, can there be a submit button on the bottom to submit all of them at once?

Comment: @MarcoDeleon: Yes instead of two Add buttons you can have only one Submit button, that would be more useful and efficient.

Comment: @MarcoDeleon: What is the output that you are expecting?

Comment: I am expecting to have the output appear in the text area. I have four fields in total that i want to output to the text area.

Comment: It is sorting the text alphabetically and i just want it to output it in the way that im entering it. how would i fix that?

Comment: @MarcoDeleon: I have edited the snippet acc to your requirements. Please check. Remove `names.Sort()` to remove the sorting and made a loop to get all the values of the field and show them on single click of Add button. Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
   var fInput  = document.getElementById("firstName");
   var lInput   = document.getElementById("lastName");
         var displayValue = document.getElementById("textDisplay");
   var fullNames  = [];
       function insertNames(){
         fullNames.push( fInput.value );
     fullNames.push( lInput.value );
     fullNames.sort();
     displayTextvalue();
       }
       function displayTextvalue(){
      // Clear our fields
      fInput.value = "";
      lInput.value = "";
      // Show our output
      displayValue.innerHTML = "";
      displayValue.innerHTML += fullNames.join(", ");

       }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lab8.js"></script>
 <title>Input Form Web Page</title>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Input Form Webpage</h1>
     <p>Enter two or more names in the field below,
     and the sorted list of names will appear in the
     textarea.</p>
 <form name="theform" >
  First Name: <br/>
     <input type="text" id="firstName" size="20" /><br/>
     <br/>
  Last Name: <br/>
  <input type="text" id="lastName" size="20" /><br/>
  <br/>
     <input type="button" name="addname" value="Add"
     onclick="insertNames()">
     <br/>
  <h2>Sorted Names</h2>
     </form>
     <textarea cols="60" rows="10" id="textDisplay" name="sorted">
     </textarea>


</body><br/>
<footer>
Marco Deleon,
Course CRN - 21819,
Date Completed: 11/6/2016,
Assignment # Lab9
</footer>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In same form each text box(from element) should have different name.

do the changes as per below in your code it will work

```js
var numbernames=0;
var names = new Array();
function SortNames() {
   // Get the name from the text field
   thename=document.theform.newname.value;
    thename1=document.theform.lastname.value;
   // Add the name to the array
   names[numbernames]=thename+"\n"+thename1;

   // Increment the counter
   numbernames++;
   // Sort the array
   names.sort();
   document.theform.sorted.value=names.join("\n");
}
```

```html
<form name="theform" >
  First Name: <br/>
     <input type="text" name="newname" size="20" /><br/>
     <input type="button" name="addname" value="Add"
     onclick="SortNames();">
     <br/>
  Last Name: <br/>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" size="20" /><br/>
     <input type="button" name="addname" value="Add"
     onclick="SortNames();">
     <br/>
  <h2>Sorted Names</h2>
     <textarea cols="60" rows="10" name="sorted">
     The sorted names will appear here.
     </textarea>
     </form>
```